# ERROR TypeError: jit_nodeValue_7(...).$any is not a function

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, visual-studio-code

when i complie mi app, i have this error, ERROR TypeError: jit_nodeValue_7(...).$any is not a function
I have tried almost everything avalible. But I am not able to find any solution I have re install all packeges, and update bur nothing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n889a.png)

my package.json is

```
"dependencies": {
"@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.0",
"@angular/animations": "^4.3.1",
"@angular/cdk": "^5.1.0",
"@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^5.2.1",
"@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/material": "^5.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/platform-server": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
"angular-form-validator": "^1.6.2",
"angular-material-source": "github:angular/material",
"angular2-material-datepicker": "^0.5.0",
"animate.css": "^3.5.2",
"arrive": "^2.3.1",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.5",
"bootstrap-material-design": "^0.5.10",
"bootstrap-notify": "^3.1.3",
"bootstrap-select": "^1.12.2",
"bootstrap-tagsinput": "^0.7.1",
"chartist": "^0.9.4",
"chartist-plugin-zoom": "^0.4.0",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"datatables": "^1.10.12",
"datatables.net-bs": "^1.10.12",
"datatables.net-responsive": "^2.1.1",
"eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^4.17.47",
"fullcalendar": "^3.4.0",
"googleapis": "^19.0.0",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"jasny-bootstrap": "^3.1.3",
"jquery": "^1.12.4",
"jquery-validation": "^1.17.0",
"jvectormap": "^2.0.4",
"moment": "^2.18.1",
"ng2-nouislider": "^1.6.1",
"ng2-select": "^1.2.0",
"ngx-chips": "^1.4.6",
"nouislider": "^9.2.0",
"perfect-scrollbar": "^1.2.0",
"rxjs": "^5.5.2",
"sweetalert2": "^7.0.5",
"twitter-bootstrap-wizard": "^1.2.0",
"typescript": "^2.4.2",
"validate": "^3.0.1",
"web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
"zone.js": "^0.8.4"
```

and my component is

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { userLogin } from 'app/entities';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';

declare var $: any;

@Component({
selector: 'app-login-cmp',
templateUrl: './login.component.html'
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
private toggleButton: any;
private sidebarVisible: boolean;
private nativeElement: Node;
constructor(private element: ElementRef, private userService: UserService, ) 
{
    this.nativeElement = element.nativeElement;
    this.sidebarVisible = false;
}
public user: userLogin;
ngOnInit() {

    this.user = {username:'',downtown:'tunja',password:''};
    this.userService.loginUser(this.user); 

    var navbar: HTMLElement = this.element.nativeElement;
    this.toggleButton = navbar.getElementsByClassName('navbar-toggle')[0];

    setTimeout(function () {
        // after 1000 ms we add the class animated to the login/register card
        $('.card').removeClass('card-hidden');
    }, 700);
}

sidebarToggle() {
    var toggleButton = this.toggleButton;
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var sidebar = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-collapse')[0];
    if (this.sidebarVisible == false) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            toggleButton.classList.add('toggled');
        }, 500);
        body.classList.add('nav-open');
        this.sidebarVisible = true;
    } else {
        this.toggleButton.classList.remove('toggled');
        this.sidebarVisible = false;
        body.classList.remove('nav-open');
    }
}

//Funciones
onSubmit() {  
    this.userService.loginUser(this.user); }
```

}

and my html is

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-full-page">

<div class="full-page login-page" filter-color="black">
    <!--  you can change the color of the filter page using: data-color="blue | purple | green | orange | red | rose " -->
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-offset-3">
                    <form method="#" action="#" #loginForm="ngForm"  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
                        <div class="card card-login card-hidden">
                            <div class="card-header text-center" data-background-color="rose">
                                <h4 class="card-title">Login</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-content">

                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <i class="material-icons">email</i>
                                    </span>
                                    <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                        <label class="control-label">Usuario</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" required [(ngModel)]="user.username" name="username">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <i class="material-icons">lock_outline</i>
                                    </span>
                                    <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                        <label class="control-label">Password</label>
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" required [(ngModel)]="user.password" name="password">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="footer text-center">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-rose btn-simple btn-wd btn-lg">Iniciar sesion</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="copyright pull-right">
                &copy; {{test | date: 'yyyy'}}
                <a href="https://www.Zuama.com">Zuama</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <div class="full-page-background" style="background-image: url(../../../assets/img/login.jpeg) "></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you run ```ng --version``` and paste what is returned in your terminal?

Answer (score 1):

What version of Angular are you using after installing all your dependencies?

I got the same error each time I tried to type something in any input field, after updating Angular version from 5.0.3 to 5.2.1. After some researches, I realised I did not update the @angular/compiler version.

Once fix the version, the error disappeared. Hence, make sure you have the same version in all your Angular dependencies.